# Android OBD-II Bluetooth API sample code not working

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, obd-ii

I need to develop an Android app that retrieves data from a OBD-II Bluetooth dongle. As first step, I downloaded the API from https://code.google.com/p/android-obd-reader/ and tried to run the Sample Application in it, but it didn’t work for me. Can someone tell me who used that API and where is the error on that code? There are lots of packages and classes on it. I’m unable to clarify them.

Comment: What kind of error do you get then? 'It doesn't work' is not specific enough.

Comment: It's always ask to pair devices,I tried it using torque it works

Comment: It's very hard to understand 
What i need to do is when i click button some value need to display as toast or test view can anybody help me to do this or get value to variable

Comment: check this version https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader

Comment: HI @Tikitaka, I have facing same issue. Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 6):

It is very difficult to know which can be your problem. I have used the library you mentioned and it includes an application example that can help you to understand how the library works.

I recommend you to use the application called obdgpslogger (http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/) that includes an OBDSim module (http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html).
This module can work as an emulator of the ELM327 device. Using it under linux you will be able to emulate a Bluetooth ELM327 dongle. Using this application you will be able to get a log the Bluetooth connection and disconnection, the configuration AT commands sent to the ELM327 device and the querying rate.

I think it will be more easy than using a real vehicle.

I know that it takes some time to understand everything, but you can do it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I found that the authors encouragement was very enlightening.